# Replacing @managed operation from xml itself in spring

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I am using JMX of spring Version 2.5 in which I am using JMX 
as shown below..

```
@ManagedOperation(description = "Mark the Entry corresponding ABC flow")
@ManagedOperationParameters(value = {
        @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "def", description = "Ids of the entries that needs to be STOP"),
        @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "Comments", description = "Note on why these entries are being marked as stop") })
public void abcstop(String def, String gtr){
    StringBuffer gfhtrPresent= jmxService.abcd(Ids, comments);
    if(idsNotPresent.length()>0) 
        throw new IOARuntimeException("<font color=red><b>No data found for the following id/id's </b></font>"+idsNotPresent);
}
```

Now I want to remove the @Managedoperation annaotation and want to configure it with in XML , please advsie how can I configure the @Managedoperation , as i wan the same functionality to be run from xml itself, Please advise.
Folks please advise as I am stuck up any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the MBean using XML - see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html). But, AFAIK, there's no way with standard components to add descriptions like that.

You would have to implement your own `MBeanInfoAssembler` (or subclass one of the standard ones).

EDIT:

For example, the `AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler` gets the operation description in [createModelMBeanOperationInfo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler.java#L412) by calling `getOperationDescription()`. By default, this just returns the method name. The `MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler` (used for the annotations) overrides this method to get the description from the annotation.

So, you could subclass the `MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler` and implement the `getOperationDescription()` method to get the description from wherever you want (perhaps another property in the XML).

Similarly, the operation parameter descriptions are set up in `getOperationParameters()` so you would override that to build them. See the [MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler.java#L259) to see how he does it from the annotation.

Comment: @Garry Russell Thanks a lot can you please share an example of MBeanInfoAssembler, so that I can grasp more

Comment: Thanks a lot but my point was that can you please update a short example , can you please show me a small example which i can follow and grasp, that will be really helpful.

Comment: No; I don't have time to do your work for you; I think I gave you enough pointers. If you are not able to understand the concepts, I must ask why you need to eliminate the annotations.

Comment: here what I grasp from your understanding..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910064/name-for-managedoperation-in-spring-jmx